# How to make the page to fit screen width on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, screen

I have the one form page. I need this form scaled and fit to screen width on any device (Android, iOS, ...). How can I do it with HTML or CSS? `style="width:100%"` is not a solution in my case.

Thanks!

Comment: Use media queries. Look up responsive design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is `width:100%` not an option?

You can use media queries to target different screen sizes like so:

```
form {
    width: 800px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    form {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

The above code would make `form` 800px wide on any screen wider than 800px, and if it is displayed on a screen size equal to or below 800px wide it will be 100% instead.  You can use as many of these as you want, so for instance you could put another media query after this for `max-width: 500px` and change the form styles accordingly for screen sizes 500px and below.

Comment: I want to scale all content, not only form itself. I want scale all it's elements as well. Like when you use two fingers scale gesture on touchscreen. But on page load automatically. Try to load some page on mobile devise and then scale it down with two fingers gesture. I want the same thing on pageload.

Comment: Most mobile browsers i.e. Safari will automatically zoom to fit the wrapper width even for non responsive sites (so you will see a zoomed out "desktop" layout for the site).  If it is not doing this, you probably have `meta` tags in your `head` that are specifying some other behavior.  Can you post the entire HTML output of the page the form is on?

Comment: I can provide URL to such form http://95.57.120.158:7300/api.php?action=poll&location_id=70

Comment: Try removing this code from the `head` section: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />`  You can experiment with other values (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)) as the `viewport` meta tag is what controls mobile viewport behavior and defaults.